# Add margin to Bootstrap 3 table?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap 3 table inside a div. It is defined like this:

```
<div id="todays-table">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Train Number</th>

            <th>Status</th>

            <th>Last Attempt</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr class="danger">
            <td>2001</td>

            <td>0</td>

            <td>2015-05-12 11:25:16</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="danger">
            <td>2005</td>

            <td>0</td>

            <td>2015-05-12 11:25:16</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="success-row">
            <td>2006</td>

            <td>1</td>

            <td>2015-05-12 11:25:16</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="danger">
            <td>2007</td>

            <td>0</td>

            <td>2015-05-12 11:25:16</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="danger">
            <td>2008</td>

            <td>0</td>

            <td>2015-05-12 11:25:16</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="danger">
            <td>2009</td>

            <td>0</td>

            <td>2015-05-12 11:25:16</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="danger">
            <td>2010</td>

            <td>0</td>

            <td>2015-05-12 11:25:16</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="danger">
            <td>2011</td>

            <td>0</td>

            <td>2015-05-12 11:25:16</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="danger">
            <td>2012</td>

            <td>0</td>

            <td>2015-05-12 11:25:16</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="danger">
            <td>2013</td>

            <td>0</td>

            <td>2015-05-12 11:25:16</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

The problem is there is no padding on the table and it goes to the very edges of the web browser like this:

[image: Table]

How do I add padding to this bootstrap table? I tried `<div id="todays-table" style="padding: 20px;">` and `table { padding: 20px; }`, neither of which worked. Can someone point in the right direction on how to do this please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want margin, not padding:

```
#todays-table {
    margin: 20px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/wzrfaLff/)**

Better, set styles on a reusable class:

```
.padded {
    margin: 20px;
}

<div id="todays-table" class="padded">
```

That said, Bootstrap's grid system does a nice job of that type of thing without additional CSS:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" id="todays-table">
```

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/wzrfaLff/3)**

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 1):

Try adding some styles to the `td`s themselves

```
div#todays-table > table.table td {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

**EDIT**

Just re-read the question, this should be more what you are after:

```
div#todays-table > table.table {
    margin: 20px;
}
```